# Run batch file with wildcard jre*.exe installation java

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to a script using batch file.

this is installation of java.

I can run using this script

```
@echo off

jre-8u71-windows-x64 /s  /L C:\setup_java.log
```

I want to automate the installation because you know java always each of everytime has update

My idea was instead using the whole filename. I would rather use the jre*.exe so i will put the installation on one folder batch would search for jre-8u71-windows-x64.exe

I have seen some script like this but this is not working.

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('jre*.exe /s  /L C:\setup_java.log') DO %%G
```

any idea? pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%# in (jre*.exe) do (
   FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('%%# /s  /L C:\setup_java.log') DO echo %%G
)
```

?